Timezone error creating SQL instance in Azure using Terraform
I am trying to crease a managed SQL instance in Azure and keep running into issues with the timezone. I am trying to use the EST timezone. I have tried EST and America/Indianapolis and I am still unable to resolve the error. I keep getting this error

Failure sending request:
│ StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidTimezone"   Message="'America/Indianapolis' is not a supported timezone."

Below is the TF been used to create this resource. Any help is greatly appreciated.
  resource "azurerm_mssql_managed_instance" "sql" {
  name                         = var.sql_instance_name
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.az-rg-details.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.az-rg-details.location
  administrator_login          = var.admin_login
  administrator_login_password = var.admin_password
  license_type                 = "BasePrice"
  subnet_id                    = azurerm_subnet.sql-subnet.id
  sku_name                     = var.sku_name
  vcores                       = var.vcores
  storage_size_in_gb           = var.storage_size_in_gb
  timezone_id = "America/Indianapolis"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.sql-subnet-nsg-association,
    azurerm_subnet_route_table_association.sql-subnet-route-table-association,
  ]
}


MySQL <> SQL Server - please ensure you use the correct tags.

Hi @Abby, The above error you're getting due to incorrect Time zone ID, you can refer the supported Time zones in Azure SQL Managed Instance for more details.


Timezone error creating SQL instance in Azure using Terraform

The above error you encountered is due to an incorrect time zone ID being passed in the Terraform code. If you want to create the EST time zone, you can use the time zone ID below. For more details about supported Time Zone IDs for Azure SQL Managed Instance, follow the MS Doc.
Eastern Standard Time
Canada Central Standard Time
US Eastern Standard Time

Here is the updated terraform code to create Azure SQL Managed Instance in EST Time Zone.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "8332bf56-aa7c-4daa-a507-d7e60e5f09a9"
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "sqldb-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "sql-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "sql-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/24"]

    delegation {
    name = "managedinstancedelegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/unprepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_managed_instance" "example" {
  name                = "sqldemodatabasetest"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  license_type       = "BasePrice"
  sku_name           = "GP_Gen5"
  storage_size_in_gb = 32
  subnet_id          = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  vcores             = 4
  timezone_id        = "Eastern Standard Time"

  administrator_login          = "Venkat"
  administrator_login_password = "Qazwsxedc!23rfnhkt"
}

After running the terraform , the SQL managed instance has been created successfully in EST Time Zone.

Reference: azurerm_mssql_managed_instance


Failure sending request:
│ StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidTimezone" Message="'America/Indianapolis' is not a supported timezone."

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same terraform code.
The cause of the issue is that the time zone value: EST or America/Indianapolis is not valid.
To solve this issue, you can set the timezone_id to US Eastern Standard Time to use the EST Time zone.
Terraform sample:
  resource "azurerm_mssql_managed_instance" "sql" {
  name                         = var.sql_instance_name
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.az-rg-details.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.az-rg-details.location
  administrator_login          = var.admin_login
  administrator_login_password = var.admin_password
  license_type                 = "BasePrice"
  subnet_id                    = azurerm_subnet.sql-subnet.id
  sku_name                     = var.sku_name
  vcores                       = var.vcores
  storage_size_in_gb           = var.storage_size_in_gb
  timezone_id = "US Eastern Standard Time"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.sql-subnet-nsg-association,
    azurerm_subnet_route_table_association.sql-subnet-route-table-association,
  ]
}

